# Is it possible to disable source maps for certain files in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

I'd like to hide a part of my code from being shown in chrome dev tools. Is it possible with webpack?

Comment: even if the sources don't show in the source map, the minified sources can still be read if someone really wants to. see if a Javascript obfuscator is not really what you are looking for https://javascriptobfuscator.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could create an [identity loader](http://webpack.github.io/docs/how-to-write-a-loader.html#examples) who filters out sourcemaps for these particular files.

```js
// remove-sourcemap.loader.js
module.exports = function(source, map) {
  this.callback(null, source)
};
```

Then, in your webpack config:

```js
module: {
  loaders: [
    include: [/* list of files (absolute path) for which to remove sourcemaps */],
    loader: 'remove-sourcemap',
  ],
},
```

You could also manually apply the [`SourceMapDevToolPlugin`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#sourcemapdevtoolplugin) instead of using the `devtool` configuration option. The plugin supports asset matching in the same way loaders do.