# failed to load source map in ASP.NET MVC after publish to hosting site

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, popper.js

When i run the website i got this error on developer tools :

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.0.1
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://aljawd.com/Contents/css/aos.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://aljawd.com/Contents/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://aljawd.com/Contents/js/aos.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://aljawd.com/Contents/js/popper.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for http://aljawd/Contents/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
```

I checked the following solutions but i cannot solve my issue , i need more explain please :

I removed the commented line in popper.min.js and aos.js and bootstrap.min.js

but may i need to have the map source files in my project under js folder and css folder ?

bootstrap.min.js.map

popper.min.js.map

aos.css.map

aos.js.map

Also i cannot find the source for google chrome under settings no source for windows 10 professional i cannot find the source to enable javascript source map ?

The error also appear on Microsoft edge last version for windows 10 :

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 3.0.1
popper.min.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: popper is not defined
    at popper.min.js:5
bootstrap.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'js' of undefined
    at bootstrap.min.js:7
aos.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: aos is not defined
    at aos.js:2
```

this is the complete path for css and js folder :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700|Work+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/fonts/icomoon/style.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/bootstrap.min.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/magnific-popup.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/jquery-ui.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/owl.carousel.min.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/owl.theme.default.min.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/animate.css")>

<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css")>

<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/aos.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/style.css")>

<script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js")></script>
        <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js")></script>
        <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/jquery-ui.js")></script>
        <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/popper.min.js")></script>
        <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/bootstrap.min.js")></script>
        <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/owl.carousel.min.js")></script>
        <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/jquery.stellar.min.js")></script>
        <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js")></script>
        <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js")></script>
        <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/aos.js")></script>
        <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/main.js")></script>
```

How to solve this error please ?

I copy paste file contents from github site

```
https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/tree/master/ajax/libs/aos/2.1.1
```

but now these files give another error

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for http://localhost:2674/Contents/css/aos.css.map: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for http://localhost:2674/Contents/js/aos.js.map: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for http://localhost:2674/Contents/js/bootstrap.min.js.map: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
```

what is the best way to read the js and css file path from my project or use the cdn site path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download the missing files from the following links and errors will not appear and hide.
Download source from this link and you will get the file

bootstrap.min.js.map

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/
```

also download the aos.css.map and aos.js.map from this

```
https://www.cdnpkg.com/aos/file/aos.css.map/
```

download file popper.min.js.map from this link

```
https://forgemia.inra.fr/genotoul-bioinfo/dgenies/blob/4c89661fba50d59fc12aeb41191fab4dd82e9216/js/popper.min.js.map
```

after download paste the files under `js folder` and `css folder` .